# How to marshall JAXB object to a different schema?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I unmarshall an XML that comes in a specific format e.g.

```
<root>
   <a/>
   <b/>
   <c>
     <x/>
   </c>
   <d/>
</root>
```

After playing around with the Java object, I want to send it to another service that uses a different schema, e.g.

```
<anotherRoot>
   <a/>
   <x/>
   <something>
      <d/>
   </something>
</anotherRoot>
```

Can this be done "easily" w/ JAXB?

Comment: think more details will help to answer.,

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried marshalling your object while specifying a different schema?  It seems like a quick try might answer your question... Also, maybe you could write a method that converts one java object into another.

Comment: Here is an example of how it could be done with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Answer (score 3):

Using any [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation you could use XSLT on a `JAXBSource` and the `javax.xml.transform` APIs to produce a secondary XML structure:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

    // Output XML conforming to first XML Schema
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

    // Create Transformer on Style Sheet that converts XML to 
    // conform the second XML Schema
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(
            "src/example/stylesheet.xsl");
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

    // Source
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, foo);

    // Result
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    // Transform
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**Full Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create create a proxy for the other service and regard its beans as simple data transfer objects.

So when you wish to call the service, you manually fill the beans based on the values of your proper model objects (the one you play around with, the ones that contain business logic) and call the service using the beans.

If changes happen to the service's interface, you can recreate the proxy and the compiler will help you fix the transformation.